Calling ASP.NET Web Service through PostMan
I am trying to call asmx web service RetrieveFacsimile method through PostMan. I am passing all parameters and security token information in SOAP Envelope. I am getting 400 Bad request error message. Not sure what I am doing wrong. any Idea?


Below is the SOAP Envelop
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap12:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>xxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>xxxxxxxxx</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <RetrieveFacsimile xmlns="http://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/services">
      <dataSeries>Call</dataSeries>
      <reportingPeriodEndDate>12/31/2023</reportingPeriodEndDate>
      <fiIDType>ID_RSSD</fiIDType>
      <fiID>9830298</fiID>
      <facsimileFormat>SDF</facsimileFormat>
    </RetrieveFacsimile>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
</xml>

below are the service and wsdl file information.
Service URL
WSDl File

Remove <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"> and </xml> in payload, try again.

I got difference from 400 Bad Request Error to 500 Internal Server Error after removing  tag.

That may be because of invalid credentials or wrong data.. I just tried now and its same error I am getting. Let me close and try again

I just tried and I am getting same error. 

400 Bad Request



400 Bad Request


Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2


This is my Postman screenshot in here

Please my output here [link]https://app.gemoo.com/share/image-annotation/644368803498983424?codeId=MpOl1kz5QpnqJ&origin=imageurlgenerator&card=644368802806923264

I think your header's problem. This is my header

yes, you are right. Its header problem. Now I am getting same error. any idea about the error? What am I missing?

500 error is server's problem, I have no idea to address  but general approch to start by SOAP-UI in here and here try by SOAP-UI version 5.7.2

Thank you. You made my day. Just need to add SOAPAction and change the contenttype.

Good to hear you got it.

@Bench Vue - do you know how to create YAML file for this wsdl file?

I no experience it but online converter can do it. I tested your WSDL. it can be convert.
